# Execute sp_addrolemember on specified database in SQL Server 2008 (or an alternative method)

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I am trying to set a trigger on the dbo.restorehistory table in an attempt to verify user roles after database restores. The trigger simply queries 'destination_database_name' when a restore logs to the history table. I then attempt to run 'EXEC sp_addrolemember' on the database in question. Apparently, however, the procedure does not exist outside the scope of the database, i.e. it is unavailable inside the trigger.

So does anyone have a suggestion as to how to manage this task? Apart from the obvious fact that my method does not work, there could be better methods entirely.

In very short terms, I need to be able to add a user and set him to db_owner after restores.

The problem with these restores is that they are executed remotely from a 3rd party application which we have no control over. When they create a new database, they execute a restore to populate the database with default data and thus overwrite the user roles that we have specifically set, even though we have them specified in the model database. So...

1. A third party program creates a database
2. The database inherits users from the model database
3. The third party program overwrites the users by restoring a default database
4. I need to have those users recreated and have their roles applied

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterRestore] 
       ON  [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
       AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       DECLARE @DatabaseName AS VARCHAR(100)
         SELECT @DatabaseName = destination_database_name
         FROM INSERTED
         CREATE USER [XYZZY Users] FOR LOGIN [domain\xyzzyusers]
         EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'XYZZY Users'
    END
    GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the database context from within the trigger you will need to use dynamic sql. A simple example is below

```
declare @DatabaseName nvarchar(100) = 'YourDB';

declare @cmd nvarchar(max);
set @cmd = replace('

    select db_name();

    use $dbname$;

    select db_name();
', '$dbname$', @DatabaseName);

print @cmd
exec sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Comment: Of course this comes with the obligatory warning about using dynamic sql.  You are not taken user input into your statement, but the risk is still something to consider.

Comment: I just wanted to reassure you that you have not answered in vain; I have simply been forced to put my focus elsewhere for the time being. As soon as I am in the clear I will put your suggestion to use. So thank you for your reply, it does indeed look like the way to go.